# Brauer Group - A measure of complexity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

I have seen many authors state that the Brauer Group in some way measures the complexity of a field. I've convinced myself that the Brauer group of the reals is Z/2Z, and that the Brauer group of an algebraically closed field is trivial, but I don't quite understand what these authors mean by "the brauer group is a measure of complexity." It would make a nice conclusion to my project on Central Simple Algebras if I could explain this; the final section of it involved the construction of the Brauer Group and Examples.

Comment: People often say that the absolute Galois group of a field is a measure of its complexity - and this can be made fairly precise insofar as it measures how complicated the classification of its algebraic extensions is - and the Brauer group is a Galois cohomology group, so it measures how complicated the absolute Galois group is! Or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately,  I haven't done any Galois stuff yet, so I can't really refer to it in my project =(

Comment: It measures the ability of the field to support interesting central simple algebras.

Comment: Ok I guess that makes sense, thanks.